# What is the best way to declare multiple argument constructor in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

When creating a class like this one:

```
class Test {
 public:
   ...

private:
   string s1_;
   string s2_;
   vector<int> v_;
};
```

What is the best way to declare a constructor accepting two strings and a vector? And, more specifically, how do you handle lvalue and rvalue references?

I see the three following options:

1. Create every combination of lvref and rvref:

   ```
      Test(const string& s1, const string& s2, const vector<int>& v) :
         s1_{s1}, s2_{s2}, v_{v}
      {
         ...
      }

      Test(const string& s1, const string& s2, vector<int>&& v) :
         s1_{s1}, s2_{s2}, v_{move(v)}
      {
         ...
      }

      Test(const string& s1, string&& s2, const vector<int>& v) :
         s1_{s1}, s2_{move(s2)}, v_{v}
      {
         ...
      }

      Test(const string& s1, string&& s2, vector<int>&& v) :
         s1_{s1}, s2_{move(s2)}, v_{move(v)}
      {
         ...
      }

      Test(string&& s1, const string& s2, const vector<int>& v) :
         s1_{move(s1)}, s2_{s2}, v_{v}
      {
         ...
      }

      Test(string&& s1, const string& s2, vector<int>&& v) :
         s1_{move(s1)}, s2_{s2}, v_{move(v)}
      {
         ...
      }

      Test(string&& s1, string&& s2, const vector<int>& v) :
         s1_{move(s1)}, s2_{move(s2)}, v_{v}
      {
         ...
      }

      Test(string&& s1, string&& s2, vector<int>&& v) :
         s1_{move(s1)}, s2_{move(s2)}, v_{move(v)}
      {
         ...
      }
   ```

   Pros: Every possibility handled efficiently.

   Cons: Requires a lot of code to handle every combination and might be error prone.
2. Always copy and move the arguments:

   ```
      Test(string s1, string s2, vector<int> v) :
         s1_{move(s1)}, s2_{move(s2)}, v_{move(v)}
      {
         ...
      }
   ```

   Pros: Only one ctor.

   Cons: Not as efficient because move does not mean free.
3. Use "universal references":

   ```
      template <typename S1, typename S2, typename V>
      Test(S1&& s1, S2&& s2, V&& v) :
         s1_{forward<S1>(s1)}, s2_{forward<S2>(s2)}, v_{forward<V>(v)}
      {
         ...
      }
   ```

   Pros: One ctor that handles everything efficiently.

   Cons: Not really meaningful. What are s1, s2 and v? Can be even more error prone (e.g. `Test error{1,2,3}` compiles).

Is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: Note: They're not called "left value references". They're just "lvalue references". It's not an abbreviation or anything; the proper term is "lvalue".

Comment: _Use universal references_ - universal reference is `S1&& s`, but not `S1 s`.

Comment: "Move does not mean free", but until you've identified a performance issue, it might as well be.  Remember that the compiler can optimise out primitive copies on the stack.

Comment: @soon Yes of course S1&&, sorry for the typo, I edited to correct this. However to be sure that a universal reference ctor is used correctly you have to rely on std::enable_if. It's not really easy to understand at first what is intended.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas My bad, I always assumed that lvalue meant left value. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @piemur BTW, the name `lvalue` historically *does* originally come from the concept "left value", but the proper name from the standard and in common technical use really is `lvalue`. If you try to expand it back out to "left value" when talking about an `lvalue` it is just confusing and non-specific.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
template <typename String, typename VectorInt>
Test(String &&s1, String &&s2, VectorInt &&v,
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::decay<String>::type,std::string>::value &&
  std::is_same<typename std::decay<VectorInt>::type,std::vector<int>>::value>::type * = nullptr) :
  s1_(std::forward<String>(s1)), s2_(std::forward<String>(s2)),
  v_(std::forward<VectorInt>(v))
{}
```